# Applying multiple filters at once in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video that I am trying to apply two filters to. I want to rotate the video 90 degrees clockwise followed by scaling it down from 1280 x 720 to 720 x 576 with letterboxing.

I also want to rotate the input file, then put the output file in a temporary folder for the other filter to use the file in the temporary folder to scale and pad, then overwrite it.

Below are the commands I am currently trying:

```
-i "<FullSourceFileName>" -vf "transpose=1" -r 30 -qscale 0 -acodec copy -f avi "C:\FfmpegTemp\Temp.avi"
```

And:

```
-i "C:\FfmpegTemp\Temp.avi" -filter:v "scale=1280*min(720/1280\,576/720):720*min(720/1280\,576/720), pad=720:576:(720-1280*min(720/1280\,576/720))/2:(576-720*min(720/1280\,576/720))/2" -vcodec rawvideo  -y "<OutputFileName>.avi"
```

Comment: Hi Ben. Can you please clarify: Do you *need* the temporary file? If you want to apply the multiple filters at once, why even use a temporary file in the first place? That'd be almost equivalent to just  calling `ffmpeg` twice.

Comment: Hi, no I don't need to keep the temporary file. I am using ffmpeg through 'AnotherGUI' in order to automate the process. So I didn't want to have to add an input file at each stage, as I couldn't get all the filters to work in one go. Thanks

Comment: So, couldn't you just use `-vf "transpose=1, scale=…"`? I haven't tried your example, but you can basically concatenate any filter.

Answer (score 9):

You already use two filters in your second example. They are separated by a comma.

Adding all three into the `-vf` parameter it looks like this:

```
-i "<FullSourceFileName>" -vf "transpose=1, scale=1280*min(720/1280\,576/720):720*min(720/1280\,576/720), pad=720:576:(720-1280*min(720/1280\,576/720))/2:(576-720*min(720/1280\,576/720))/2" -r 30 -qscale 0 -acodec copy -f avi -vcodec rawvideo  -y "<OutputFileName>.avi"
```